# Single sign-on for SharePoint site on windows clients

Tags: windows, sharepoint, active-directory, windows-authentication

Can i remove the need for windows clients to log on to SharePoint intranet sites? Sort of pushing out their group policies to allow access to certain intranet sites?

Thank
B

Comment: Are we talking about clients where the user is logged in with his current domain user on the machine - the same user used for the SharePoint intranet?

Comment: Yes, this exactly the case

Comment: Your question should not be on StackOverflow as it is for programming related questions. ServerFault or SharePoint would be the correct sites.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the browser (e.g. Internet Explorer) to automatically log the user on for your Intranet sites. Internet Explorer does this automatically for sites in the **Local Intranet Zone**. If you access your Intranet via intranet.company.com, IE doesn't know that it is a local Intranet site and treats it as an Internet sites, meaning it doesn't automatically log you on.

You have to manually add the respective URL as a local intranet site:

- Go to Tools > Options > Security > Local intranet > Sites > Advanced
- Add your site there e.g. intranet.company.com or *.company.com

You will be automatically logged into SharePoint.

The same procedure is possible for Firefox, you only have to edit the NTLM trusted Uri's in `about:config`. Chrome automatically uses the IE security settings.

All these settings are also deployable via group policy.

Comment: Thanks, but i was wondering if the system administrator would be able to do this centrally as it is described below: http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/325-deploy-ie-trusted-sites-through-group-policy-2008

Comment: Yes, as described in your article as well as stated in my answer: use a group policy.

Comment: Thanks, i'm asking because i'm not familiar with the method described in the article and wanted to confirm if this is actually what they are referring to. And does this require the client to do anything?

Comment: No. You can push group policy settings in your active directory any way you want. If you deem necessary, you can even restrict clients from changing them themselves, so only the Admin can make changes.